# Node.js 5.5.0 console.log won't log

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console.log

I can't get any terminal output when I call console.log("anything") anywhere in my app. The issue seems to have started when I updated node to 5.5.0, before that I had no issues. What's going on? I'm not sure what other information would be relevant. I'm running a standard Node.js http server with express.

Here is my server.js file. It's a little ugly right now...but in any case:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var cors = require('cors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var keys = require('./config/keys/apiKeys');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var validator = require('validator');
var fs = require('fs');
var ParseCloud = require('parse-cloud-express');
var Parse = ParseCloud.Parse;

require('console-stamp')(console, [])

var http = require('http').Server(app);
var https = require('https');

// config =========================================================================================

/*SSL */
var hskey = fs.readFileSync('./config/keys/theExperiment-key.pem');
var hscert = fs.readFileSync('./config/keys/theExperiment-cert.pem')

var options = {
    key: hskey,
    cert: hscert
};

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use('/webhooks', ParseCloud.app);

require('./config/passport')(passport); //pass passport for configuration

app.use(bodyParser.json()); //get all data/stuff of the body (POST) parameters, parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); //parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(methodOverride("X-HTTP-Method-Override")); //override with the x-http-method-override header in the request. simulate delete/put
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users

//use template engine
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use(morgan('dev')); //log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); //read cookies

//required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
})); //session secret and defaults
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); //persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); //use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
app.use(cors()); //allow cross origin resource sharing

Parse.initialize(keys.parse.applicationId, keys.parse.javascriptKey, keys.parse.masterKey); //Init Parse


// routes ===========================================================================================

require('./app/routes')(app, passport, io); //configure our routes, pass in app and passport

// socketIO =========================================================================================

require('./app/sockets')(io,passport); //require socketio control


// start app ========================================================================================

http.listen(port);
console.log('Hello ' + port);

//expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Here is my gruntfile.js (as mentioned in the comments):

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    // JS TASKS ================================================================
    // check all js files for errors
    jshint: {
      all: ['public/src/**/*.js'] 
    },

    // take all the js files and minify them into app.min.js
    uglify: {
      build: {
        files: {
          'public/dist/js/app.min.js': ['public/src/**/*.js', 'public/src/*.js']
        }
      }
    },

    // CSS TASKS ===============================================================
    // process the less file to style.css
    less: {
      build: {
        files: {
          'public/dist/css/style.css': 'public/src/css/style.less'
        }
      }
    },

    //configure autoprefixing for compiled output css
    autoprefixer: {
      build: {
        files: {
          'public/dist/css/style.css': 'public/dist/css/style.css'
        }
      }
    },

    // take the processed style.css file and minify
    cssmin: {
      build: {
        files: {
          'public/dist/css/style.min.css': 'public/dist/css/style.css'
        }
      }
    },

    // COOL TASKS ==============================================================
    // watch css and js files and process the above tasks
    watch: {
      css: {
        files: ['public/src/css/**/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less', 'autoprefixer', 'cssmin']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['public/src/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'uglify']
      }
    },

    // watch our node server for changes
    nodemon: {
      dev: {
        script: 'server.js',
        options: {
          max_old_space_size: "2048"
        }
      }
    },

    // run watch and nodemon at the same time
    concurrent: {
      options: {
        logConcurrentOutput: true
      },
      tasks: ['nodemon', 'watch']
    },

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'autoprefixer', 'cssmin', 'jshint', 'uglify', 'concurrent']);

};
```

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this is a bug in Node.js 5.5.0. Is your app behaving normally otherwise?

Comment: Does it start up and run without problems?

Comment: Yes, nothing else seems to be off. The only other thing I've noticed is that when running with nodemon, the output used to be "starting 'node server.js'" \n "server running" (or something similar). And now the "server running" message no longer displays, although the server does actually start and function as normal.

Comment: get rid of everything, just have a server.js file that has console.log ..

Comment: Same output...nothing:

[nodemon] restarting due to changes... \n
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

Nodemon used to log "server running" after that, and "hello 8080" should be the console.log output.

Comment: and... remove nodemon from the equation? clearly you've proved it isn't your code, seems like the only logical step would be to remove nodemon as the next debugging step.

Comment: Hmmm seems like we've found the source of the problem. Without grunt/nodemon it logs fine. Just gotta figure out what's causing that. Added the gruntfile.js in the initial question

Comment: I'd suspect nodemon, it has had this kind of problem in the past.

Comment: What is that `console-stamp` module and what is it doing to `console`?

Comment: @Bergi console-stamp just adds a timestamp (or other formatting) before console output. The error still existed after removing that. ex. [26/06/2015 12:44:31.777] [LOG]   This is a console.log message

Comment: @KevinB is there anything that can be done or is that a nodemon bug?

Comment: Might be time to open an issue at the nodemon git repo. i don't see one for this particular issue. Make sure you're using the latest version of nodemon and all related modules first though.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It ended up being an outdated version of nodemon. After updating to the latest version the problem was solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate you issue. 94% of the time when you don't see console logs printing to the terminal it's due to to stdin and stdout of different processes.

1. Run `node server.js`.
   If that works:
2. Run `nodemon server.js`.
   If that works:
3. Remove `console-stamp` completely.
   If that doesn't fix it:
4. Remove `concurrent` from the grunt file default and run `nodemon` task directly in the chain.
   If that doesn't fix it:
5. Make sure you're running the latest versions of all installed dependancies in your package.json and that they are all updated and compatible with the version of node you have upgraded to.

Comment: Thank you, it ended up being an outdated version of nodemon that was incompatible with the node 5.5.0